# Convert and Store Date and Time in other coloumn in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, database, timezone, timestamp-with-timezone

I have database in MYSQL with ID, Req_Order_No(Varchar) , Req_In_Time(DateTime), Req_Out_Time(DateTime)

The Sample row is like below:

```
1   W0CH546  2014-07-23 09:32:00   2014-07-24 01:42:00
```

The above Date and Time are in EST format. I want to convert both of them and store in IST format in other columns

I tried `SELECT CONVERT_TZ('Req_In_Time','-05:00','+9:30');`

But it returns NULL Values.

Please help. Do I need php also?

Comment: Remove the quotes from the column name (`'Req_In_Time'` -> `Req_In_Time`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The quotes around Req_In_Time cause the error.

```
SELECT CONVERT_TZ(Req_In_Time,'-05:00','+9:30');
```

Also, you should never store time information in localtime. 
Use UTC/GMT.

You can always convert it to the proper localtime when you display it.

Note: Of course you need to specify the table-name as well:

```
SELECT CONVERT_TZ(Req_In_Time,'-05:00','+9:30') FROM YOUR_TABLE_NAME;
```

So you add another column (e.g. column xxx) to YOUR_TABLE_NAME.
Then you update the values.

```
UPDATE YOUR_TABLE_NAME
     SET xxx = CONVERT_TZ(Req_In_Time,'-05:00','+9:30')
```

BTW, to add the column:

```
ALTER TABLE YOUR_TABLE_NAME ADD COLUMN `xxx` datetime NULL ;
```

Comment: It showed up this Error:
# 1054 - Field 'Req_In_Time unknown in field list

Comment: @user3766876: Well, you should specify the table name as well. Edited answer.

Comment: Thanks Buddy!!! Just One more problem now how should I store it in other coloumn directly without Exporting And Importing?

Comment: @user3766876: Already added that information a few seconds ago.